# Seperate Collection for each customer's bulk data?

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I am suddenly in a situation where I need to come up with a back-end design for some bulk data. A lot of critical data is actually stored in RDBMS (user, login, important details etc) but there is some bulk 'events' data that the project lead feels will be better off in a NoSQL DB like MongoDB. So here's the scenario: The system will have a lot of data coming in periodically, sometimes as low as once every 10 seconds. And this data needs to go to MongoDB. Now what would be a better design - create a new collection for every customer? Or store all the information in one collection. There will be tens of thousands of records coming in for each customer, so any tips on the design should be? MongoDB is totally new to me but I can't escape from this situation that I am in. Any pointers will be greatly helpful. Thanks

Comment: and how this data will be used later on? how frequently you will be retrieving the data?

Comment: Well, the retrieval is generally only when the user logs into the portal. Then I have an ajax call that will periodically keep fetching the data from MongoDB and keep doing that as long as the user is logged in. The user will be able to filter the records based on datetime. For example he may want to view records created between dates A and B. So I will be adding a datetime string to the incoming json string.